# Can geoNear in MongoDB return a subset of fields in a document?

Tags: mongodb

When using geoNear it returns all the fields/entire document for the 
objects it finds, is there any way to limit it to a subset of fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently not supported. The only workaround is using $near and do the distance calculation (dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)) yourself