# Spring data mongoDB GeoNear query with excluding fields

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, spring-data

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or it is a bug.
I have the following code:

```
    Query criteria = new Query(Criteria.where("locationTime").gte(
            "date-time"));
    criteria.fields().exclude("friends");

    NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(point).maxDistance(maxDistance)
            .num(limit).query(criteria);
    GeoResults<Profile> result = mongoTemplate
            .geoNear(query, Profile.class);
```

I am executing the query and profiles near by retrieved correctly according to distance and the "locationTime" criteria but it seems to ignore the excluded field and retrieving the profiles with their friends.

When I use simple query the exclude/include fields works perfectly.
I looked every where and could not find any resemble use-case, please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to limit the fields with a `geoNear` command, as far as I know.

I looked into calling `executeCommand` to try to work around the limitations of Spring Data, but it looks like they don't even have a way to do it from the raw command.

Comment: I have a lot of data i want to exclude in the GeoNear queries.. are you telling me that it must retrieve the full document? is there any work around? that way it will be freaking slow..

Comment: You could try using `$near` in a regular find syntax. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-Querying It can't do everything that `geoNear` can, but if you can fit your query into it, you can limit fields, as you usually would with find.

Comment: thank you ... are you basically saying that in mongo geo near query excluding fields is not supported? or it is a spring-data issue?

Comment: It's a mongo issue, rather than a spring data thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782080/can-geonear-in-mongodb-return-a-subset-of-fields-in-a-document also. I couldn't find a ticket for a feature request for it--maybe people don't use geoNear with big documents. Seems like a valid feature.

Comment: do you have any idea if I can perform the near query via mongoTemplate (Spring-data)?, it seems that API only provide geoNear method..

Comment: Yeah, you would do a `find`, but specify a `$near` key/value.